# If $A$ is any proper subset of an infinite set $X$, then does there exist injection from $X$ to $A$?

Tags: set-theory

I have a question "Let $X$ be an infinite set and $x_0 \in X$, then prove that $X \setminus \{x_0 \}$ is also an infinite set."

I have this proposition, "If $A$ is any proper subset of infinite set $X$, then there exists an injection from $X$ to $A$." I don't know if it is true or not, I am thinking to use it, to prove above statement. Is there any example which contradicts this proposition? Or is the proposition true?

Comment: Do the real numbers inject into the integers?

Comment: $A = \emptyset$?

Comment: $\{1, 2 \} \subseteq \Bbb N$.

Comment: what makes you think the proposition is false?

Comment: @CSquared Above comments seem to show on why it is or can be false. I can say you why I have notion of it being true, if we can find a set {a,b,c,d .....}, such that its every proper subset can't be put into injection, then it won't be an infinite set.

Comment: the comments do not imply that the statement can be false... the comments are suggesting that you think about a finite subset of an infinite set.

Comment: @CSquared The comments **do** imply that the statement is false. The statement was "for any subset of $A$ of an infinite set $X$, there exists an injection from $X$ to $A$". The comments disprove the statement by providing examples of sets $A\subset X$ for which there is no injection from $X$ to $A$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann wow, that was confusing. total typo, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lulu's comment above indicates, this proposition is not true in general.

Your proposition touches on the set-theoretic notion of a set's cardinality ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality)). There exists an injection $f\colon A \to B$ if and only if $\lvert A \rvert \le \lvert B \rvert$. Thus, for any set $X$ of infinite cardinality, and a finite subset $A \subset X$, there does not exist an injective function $f \colon X \to A$.

Restraining ourselves then to infinite subsets, we have lulu's example. Defining the cardinality of the natural numbers as $\lvert \mathbb{N} \rvert =\colon \aleph_0$, the cardinality of the real numbers is $\lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert =\colon \mathfrak{c} = \lvert \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \rvert = 2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_0$, by Cantor's theorem ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem)). Thus, although $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an infinite proper subset, there does not exist an injective function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$.

The proposition you seem to be misremembering about infinite sets is the notion of Dedekind-infinite sets (which, in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is equivalent to infinite sets). A set $X$ is Dedekind-infinite if there exists a proper subset $A \subset X$ such that there exists a bijection $f \colon X \to A$, or equivalently such that $\lvert A \rvert = \lvert X \rvert$.